# How to display special characters in flextable save_as_image routine

Tags: r, flextable

Flextable's `save_as_image`function seems to only understand ASCII characters. Is there a workaround?

### Minimal working example

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)
ft <- flextable(
  head(mtcars),
  col_keys = c("mpg"))
ft <- set_header_labels(ft, mpg = "n°")
ft

library(webshot)
if( require("webshot") ){
  save_as_image(x = ft, path = "./test.png")
}
```

### Expected output

[image]

### Actual output

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/222#issuecomment-661352316

Comment: You should add your `sessionInfo()` - I suspect you to be on Windows but not sure. This issue has been solved in the dev version (so you need to install github version)

Comment: Yes, I am on a Windows machine. Thanks! I'll test this out and give feedback asap.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
`library(devtools)`
`install_github("davidgohel/flextable")`
worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

use the unicode value for degree

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)
ft <- flextable(
  head(mtcars),
  col_keys = c("mpg"))
ft <- set_header_labels(ft, mpg = "n\u00b0")
ft

library(webshot)
if( require("webshot") ){
  save_as_image(x = ft, path = "./test.png")
}
```

[image]